# Taking Multiple screenshots of Canvas using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, canvas, jspdf

Hopefully the solution to what I would like to do is easy.  I successfully have the canvas printing to a pdf using the following code:

```
<!-- Start PDF Script -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function getPDFFileButton () {
            return html2canvas($('canvas'), {
                background: "#ffffff",
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png,1.0");
                    // Adjust width and height
                    var imgWidth = (canvas.width * 20) / 240;
                    var imgHeight = (canvas.height * 20) / 240; 
                    // jspdf changes
                    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
                    pdf.addImage(myImage, 'png', 15, 2, imgWidth, imgHeight); // 2: 19
                    pdf.save('H&H-Carport-Design.pdf');
                }
            });
        }       
        $("#btnPrint").on("click", function () {
            getPDFFileButton ()
        });
    </script>
<!-- End PDF Script -->
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" id="btnPrint">Print PDF <i class="fas align-middle fa-file-pdf"></i></button>
```

I need help modifying the code to take a picture of the canvas from the Front, Back, Left and Right and put all of the images on the same PDF when you click the "Print PDF" button.  Is this possible?

Comment: What would a "picture of the canvas from the Back" look like?  Mirror image?

Comment: Basically rotating the canvas around and taking a screenshot of the back of the 3D model

Comment: I don’t even know where to begin to do that. Are there any examples you can point me to?